# Is there a way so that my list-item can take the complete height taken by my ul?(Without hardcoding)

Tags: html, height, html-lists, inline

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="menu-item">
    <p>File</p>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item selected">
    <p>Home</p>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <p>Insert</p>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <p>Data</p>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <p>Review</p>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <p>View</p>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item">
    <p>Help</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is my code,and I want that all my list item take complete width of ul.(I have used display flex) so in this case I want my list-items to take complete height of my ul.

Answer (score 0):

Well I didn't 100% get what you wanted it to look like but here try this:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}

.menu-item{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

p{
    font-size: 20px;
}

    *{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu{
    margin-top: 20px;
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
}

.menu-item{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

p{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```